# The word for the tipping point. Point of change

Tags: verbs, nouns

Looking for the word that displays the point of change, the apex, that point or event that changed something it was the "" of the day, her thoughts, the game, etc.

Comment: The ***inflection point***?

Comment: Positive or negative?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the phrase you are looking for is *turning point*. [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turning%20point)

> a time when an important change happens

Answer (score 1):

[The Collins dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/turning-point) shows a few alternatives that I like, such as "crossroads":

> crossroads, critical moment, decisive moment, change, crisis, crux, moment of truth, point of no return, moment of decision, climacteric, tipping point

A google search for `turning point synonym` shows "landmark" amongst other options - which I quite like, depending on context.

I also like "watershed", see [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/watershed).